# Is There a Way to Playback Raw Audio/Video Streams in Android API's?

Tags: android, h.264, android-mediaplayer, vorbis

I have a Vorbis stream that I can decode to PCM if necessary, and I have a raw h264 stream all three of which are supported by Android when in a container. Wondering if there is any way to manually feed video and audio samples into the android MediaPlayer without any container. I would imagine I would have to override methods within the MediaPlayer. Does anyone have experience with this or have an easier way to do this? I can't imagine its impossible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to play the audio pcm samples (For that also, I guess you may have to put a wav header) but you may not be able to play the H264 elementary stream without a container. In the media framework (Stagefright), there are sniffers functions registered for various container formats which could tell what kind of parser need to be used and then extractor(parser) is created. I don't think that you will be able to play the H264 elementary stream from the application using the inbuilt media framework of Android.

Comment: I figured I would probably be able to get the pcm stream to work. I would imagine that StageFright would need Duration, SPS and PPS NALs, and a Timestamp for video samples at a minimum if I were to bypass the container sniffers? I wonder how netflix does it? Thanks for your answer. Its not what I wanted to here, but that is alright... :-)

Comment: Until and unless you make changes in the framework, you may not be able to tell Stagefright that you are just sending H264 NAL units/duration etc. I am not sure whether netflix uses the Android framework or not but certainly it can use NDK so that it can have its own media player and use it as the way it wants ( without using Android media framework).

Comment: I think your right. I think Netflix is using the NDK. I don't see anyway to manage a fragmented container in the Android SDK. That is too bad. Thanks for your responses.